# Why do image sizes shrink when printing multiple plots as a single object?

Tags: graphics, image, code-request

I searched the repository a lot and found no answer to the following question. My code below produces 4 plots as a group. Each plot has `ImageSize->300`. However, when I print it, the images become so tiny and not respecting the image size set.

This is a MWE.

```
simForm1 = {{1, 43, 0}, {5, 38, 1}, {25, 15, 4}, {35, 1, 8}, {23, 0, 
    21}, {17, 0, 27}, {13, 0, 31}, {11, 0, 33}, {9, 0, 35}, {8, 0, 
    36}, {5, 0, 39}, {4, 0, 40}, {4, 0, 40}, {3, 0, 41}, {2, 0, 
    42}, {2, 0, 42}, {2, 0, 42}, {0, 0, 44}};
simForm2 = {{1, 43, 0}, {15, 29, 0}, {39, 1, 4}, {22, 0, 22}, {16, 0, 
    28}, {11, 0, 33}, {5, 0, 39}, {5, 0, 39}, {3, 0, 41}, {2, 0, 
    42}, {2, 0, 42}, {2, 0, 42}, {2, 0, 42}, {1, 0, 43}, {1, 0, 
    43}, {1, 0, 43}, {1, 0, 43}, {1, 0, 43}, {0, 0, 44}};
simForm3 = {{1, 43, 0}, {2, 41, 1}, {14, 29, 1}, {35, 3, 6}, {25, 0, 
    19}, {18, 0, 26}, {13, 0, 31}, {9, 0, 35}, {8, 0, 36}, {5, 0, 
    39}, {4, 0, 40}, {2, 0, 42}, {2, 0, 42}, {2, 0, 42}, {1, 0, 
    43}, {1, 0, 43}, {1, 0, 43}, {1, 0, 43}, {1, 0, 43}, {1, 0, 
    43}, {0, 0, 44}};
simForm4 = {{1, 43, 0}, {3, 41, 0}, {14, 29, 1}, {25, 10, 9}, {22, 2, 
    20}, {17, 0, 27}, {11, 0, 33}, {11, 0, 33}, {9, 0, 35}, {6, 0, 
    38}, {5, 0, 39}, {5, 0, 39}, {3, 0, 41}, {2, 0, 42}, {0, 0, 44}};
simForm0 = {simForm1, simForm2, simForm3, simForm4};
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  Table[ListLinePlot[Transpose[simForm0[[i]]], ImageSize -> 350, 
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Shock propagation steps", "# of sectors"}, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Grid[{{"Shock propagation trajectories"}}], 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[10], 
    PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[{"Inflicted", "Susceptible", "Recovered"}, Below], 
    PlotTheme -> "Business", ImagePadding -> All], {i, 4}], UpTo[2]]]
```

Comment: You don't need to include your plots, but including a plot e.g. would mean we could just cut and paste the code (rather than inventing plots).

Comment: @mikado: I edited the question with a MWE. The code is working but the problem persists.

Comment: It doesn't look `targetedSectors` is defined?

Comment: @mikado: Use `Length[targetedSector]=4` associated with the number of plots, which is 4..

Comment: @mikado: we can combine the data sets for each plot like, `simForm1={simForm1, simForm2, simForm3, simForm4}` to use the `GraphicsGrid[...]`.

Comment: @mikado: I edited the MWE.

Comment: `plots = Table[
   ListLinePlot[Transpose[simForm0[[i]]], ImageSize -> 350, 
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Shock propagation steps", "# of sectors"}, 
    PlotLabel -> Grid[{{"Shock propagation trajectories"}}], 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[10], 
    PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[{"Inflicted", "Susceptible", "Recovered"}, Below], 
    PlotTheme -> "Business", ImagePadding -> All], {i, 4}];

Multicolumn[plots, 2]`      Look also for `Appearance->"Horizontal" `

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci: It works in this example with 4 plots. I have 10 plots and want to print them all as a single figure. I tried `Multicolumn[plots, {4,3}]` and it does not work then. Also, `Multicolumn` prints the plots as individual objects. I wanted to have a single object including 10 plots.

Comment: add the option `ImageSize -> 900` to `GraphicsGrid`?

Comment: @kglr: After adding the option, the plot labels are not fully shown; plots are distant from each other; and they are small.

Comment: Try the option: `ImagePadding -> 100`

Comment: @DanielHuber: it gets worse than before if I add the image padding 100.

Comment: It looks o.k. in MMA and when I print it with PDF24 it looks o.k. I have MMA version 14.0

Comment: @Daniel Huber: I have version 13.1 and it does not look good in my case may be due to the version difference. `Labeled[#, {"Number of sectors", "Steps of shock propagation"}, {Left,
     Bottom}, RotateLabel -> True] &@GraphicsGrid[
  Partition[
   Table[ListLinePlot[Transpose[simForm1[[i]]], 
     PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"]], {i, 
     Length[targetedSectors]}], UpTo[3]], ImageSize -> 700, 
  ImagePadding -> All
  ]` looks fine in my machine.

Answer (score 3):

From the answer to my other questions (by kglr), I produced the following answer.

```
Legended[#, 
     Placed[LineLegend[97, {"Inflicted", "Susceptible", "Recovered"}, 
       LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below]] &@
   Labeled[#, {Style["Number of sectors", Bold, 13], 
     Style["Steps of shock propagation", Bold, 13], 
     Style["Shock propagation trajectories", Bold, 13]}, {Left, 
     Bottom, Top}, RotateLabel -> True] &@
 GraphicsGrid[
  Partition[
   Table[ListLinePlot[Transpose[simForm1[[i]]], Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
     PlotLabel -> 
      Grid[{{"m = " <> ToString[m], "r= " <> ToString[r], 
         "inf= " <> ToString[targetedSectors[[i]]]}}], 
     GridLines -> Automatic], {i, Length[targetedSectors]}], UpTo[3]],
   Spacings -> 1, ImageSize -> 650, ImagePadding -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using [ResourceFunction["GraphicsInformation"]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GraphicsInformation/) we get `"ImageSize"` and `"ImagePaddingSize"` for each plot in a matrix of plots and use this information to get an image size spec for `GraphicsGrid`:

```
graphicsInfo = ResourceFunction["GraphicsInformation"];

graphicsGridImageSize = Reverse[Dimensions @ #] Map[Max] @ Transpose @
  Total[{"ImageSize", "ImagePaddingSize"} /.
    Map[graphicsInfo] @ 
      If[Head @ First @ # === Legended, #[[All, 1]], #] & @ 
      Flatten[#], {2}] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
simForm0 = {simForm1, simForm2, simForm3, simForm4};

plots = Partition[Table[
   ListLinePlot[Transpose[simForm0[[i]]], 
     ImageSize -> 350, 
     Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
     FrameLabel -> {"Shock propagation steps", "# of sectors"}, 
     PlotLabel -> Grid[{{"Shock propagation trajectories"}}], 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[10], 
     PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[LineLegend[{"Inflicted", "Susceptible", "Recovered"}], Below],
     PlotTheme -> "Business", 
     ImagePadding -> All], 
  {i, 4}], UpTo[2]];

GraphicsGrid[plots, ImageSize -> graphicsGridImageSize @ plots]
```

[image]

```
simForm0b = {simForm1, simForm2, simForm3, simForm4, simForm2, simForm3};

SeedRandom[3]; 

plotsb = Partition[Table[
 ListLinePlot[Transpose[simForm0b[[i]]], 
     ImageSize -> (250 + RandomChoice[{-100, 0, 100}]), 
     Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
     FrameLabel -> {"Shock propagation steps", "# of sectors"}, 
     PlotLabel -> Grid[{{"Shock propagation trajectories"}}], 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[10], 
     PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[LineLegend[{"Inflicted", "Susceptible", "Recovered"}],  Below], 
     PlotTheme -> "Business", ImagePadding -> All],
  {i, 6}], UpTo[3]];

GraphicsGrid[plotsb, ImageSize -> graphicsGridImageSize @ plotsb]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and answer. Now I know what to do next time.